# Tensorflow - Pad OR Truncate Sequence with Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, sequence, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use the [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) to prepare a `TFRecordDataset` of text sequences. After processing, I have a dictionary of tensors for each record. Each record contains two sequences.

I am using `padded_batch` to apply padding

```
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes= {
    'seq1': tf.TensorShape([None]),
    'seq2': tf.TensorShape([None])
})
```

This pads each sequence to the maximum sequence lengths in the batch. However, I would like to choose an arbitrary sequence length and pad to this length when the true sequence length is less else truncate the sequence.

When I try replacing `None` with `100` for example, I encounter a `DataLossError`

> DataLossError: Attempted to pad to a smaller size than the input element.

Is there a way to do this to achieve similar functionality as `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` on a sequence?

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way to pad or truncate, but you can use the `map` function to obtain a dataset containing elements with the desired length. Here's a quick example:

```
k = 4
def pad_or_trunc(t):
    dim = tf.size(t)
    return tf.cond(tf.equal(dim, k), lambda: t, lambda: tf.cond(tf.greater(dim, k), lambda: tf.slice(t, [0], [k]), lambda: tf.concat([t, tf.zeros(k-dim, dtype=tf.int32)], 0)))

vals = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
dset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(vals)
dset2 = dset1.map(pad_or_trunc)
iter = dset2.make_one_shot_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(iter.get_next()))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

Comment: This is a nice idea. However, I'd partially change it to truncating the sequence to the desired length as you did, but do the padding in a separate step -maybe by using DS.padded_batch-  This way, I'd pad smaller samples with less padding, instead of padding all samples to the same size as the longest sample. This is just an update given the new feats in TF2. I know that this solution was proposed more than a year and a half ago.

Comment: Amazing! I have no idea what's going on in your code here but it works on my videos (with a few modifications). So thank you so much. But... how would I change it for symmetrical padding? Add a zeros tensor to the concat part and change sizes to (k-dim)//2 and (k-dim)//2+1? What about the slice?

Answer (score 1):

You can first truncate all longer sequences using [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) and [tf.math.greater](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/greater), and then use [padded_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) to pad the sequences.

An example could look like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# data generator
def gen():
  for i in [np.array([1, 1, 1]), np.array([2, 2, 2, 2]), np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])]:
    yield i

cut_or_pad = 4 # 100 in your example

def cut_if_longer(el):
  if tf.greater(tf.shape(el), cut_or_pad): # only slice if longer
    return tf.slice(el, begin=[0], size=[cut_or_pad])
  return el

# data pipeline
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( gen, (tf.int32), (tf.TensorShape([None])))
dataset = dataset.map( lambda el: cut_if_longer(el))
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size=2, padded_shapes=[cut_or_pad], padding_values=-1)

list(dataset.take(2).as_numpy_iterator())
```